# Создание char массива в Rust

Tags: массивы, rust

Только начинаю изучать Rust, но уже столкнулся с одной проблемой, а именно - создание двумерного char массива. Компилятор выдает следующее:

```
let mut default_table = [[char; 5] ; 5];
                        ^^^ not a value
```

Суть в том, что каждый элемент массива должен содержать одну букву. Если есть какие-то предложения, то очень буду рад рассмотреть. Заранее спасибо

Comment: https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.array.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы путаете тип и значения.  Должно быть как-то так:

```rust
fn main() {
    const N: usize = 5;
    const M: usize = 5;
    let array: [[char; N]; M] = [
        ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'],
        ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'],
        ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'],
        ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'],
        ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'],
    ];

    println!("{:?}", array);
}
```